# Use TeX Gyre fonts with latex+dvips+ps2pdf

Tags: fonts, luatex, pstricks, dvips, tex-gyre-math

I want to use the TeX Gyre fonts (especially the Pagella and Pagella Math) with LaTeX+dvips+ps2pdf. In the future I want to use this for PSTricks but first I've to solve my font problems.

I use this code for LaTeX+dvips+ps2pdf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\begin{document}
Test in Pagella

\[\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\]
\end{document}
```

It produces a PDF file with the text in TeX Gyre Pagella *but* the mathematics in Computer Modern (see screenshot)

[image: Screenshot produced by sourcefile]

When changing the code to the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontenc,unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}
Test in Pagella

\[\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\]
\end{document}
```

and processing it with LuaLaTeX in DVI-mode works well. But running `dvips` afterwards produces the following errors

```
This is dvips(k) 5.992 Copyright 2012 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' LuaTeX output 2013.04.01:1811' -> template-pstricks.ps
kpathsea: Invalid fontname `name:TeXGyrePagella:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;', contains ':'
dvips: Font name:TeXGyrePagella:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep; not found; using cmr10

</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cmr10.pk>kpathsea: Invalid fontname `name:TeXGyrePagellaMath:mode=base;script=math;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;+ssty=1;', contains ':'

dvips: Font name:TeXGyrePagellaMath:mode=base;script=math;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;+ssty=1; not found; using cmr10

</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cmr10.pk>
dvips: ! invalid char 119899 from font name:TeXGyrePagellaMath:mode=base;script=math;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;+ssty=1;
```

I understand that dvips can't handle OpenType fonts, but how can I use the TeX Gyre Pagella and especially TeX Gyre Pagella Math together with PSTricks? Either LaTeX or LuaLaTeX solutions would be a great help.

Comment: Isn't XeLaTeX an option? It can run PSTricks directly.

Comment: XeLaTeX would be my "worst case solution". But if there's a solution with LaTeX or LuaLaTeX, I'd enjoy much more.

Comment: `auto-pst-pdf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've now solved the problem with adding `auto-pst-pdf` to the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{fontenc,unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}
Test in Pagella

\[\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\]
\end{document}
```

And compiling it with `lualatex -shell-escape file.tex` produces the following out put containing just TeX Gyre Pagella and TeX Gyre Pagella Math.

[image: Screenshot of correct result]

Great thanks to @egreg for providing this hint.

> Improved due to @Ulrike Fischer's comment

There is obiously no way to solve the problem as I wanted, so I edited my code once again

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setromanfont[Ligatures=TeX]{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\begin{document}
Test in Pagella

\[\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\]

\begin{pspicture}(3,3)
  \psline{->}(1,1)(3,2)
  \psline{->}(1,1)(3,1)
  \rput(2,2){$x$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Processing it with `xelatex file.tex` produces the wanted PDF-file, containing the TeX Gyre Pagella and Pagella Math

[image: Screenshot of processed code with xelatex]

Thanks to @egreg and @Ulrike Fischer for their hints. More improvement is welcome, I think there's a lot to learn for me.

Comment: Well you are actually not making use of auto-pst-pdf in this example: It doesn't contain any pstricks pictures which try to use your fonts. As soon as you add them you will run in the same problem: auto-pst-pdf uses dvips+ps2pdf to convert the pictures, and dvips can't handle open type fonts. The only way to handle pstricks pictures which use open type fonts is to use xelatex.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer. So my answer is not a real answer to my question, when using PSTricks. I'll try to get it work with XeLaTeX and improve to answer afterwards.

Comment: Btw, is TikZ working with LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Yes, TikZ works fine with lualatex.